# Why community in SE deleted my comment related to the below duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion, exact-duplicates

Really am sorry for the behavior of community of stackexchange math, I am the first who  has marked  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3330880/156150) as a duplicate question and I have got some up vote for this comment  After sometimes, I have got my comment deleted and the question become marked by others, Why this behavior? Really I decide to leave this website this is not good behavior

Comment: The automated removal of Comments that identify the duplicate will in some cases also take away an observation that would be helpful to the OP (original poster) or other Readers.  If that was the situation here, feel free to restate your Comment or a variation on it in light of the vote to close-as-duplicate.  And my thanks for helping with Community Moderation in this fashion!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik As explained above and by quid in the answer below, it's an automated software result. I believe it's something which is the same system wide. Thus, you can check if anybody has made a request in the main meta site, i.e., https://meta.stackexchange.com , to change this behavior and, if not, you may wish make such a request yourself.

Comment: Just to be explicit, the *upvotes* are also automatic. A comment is automatically generated when someone flags/votes to close a question as a duplicate. Each additional vote to close (and flag?) will cause the comment to be upvoted. (The comment can also be upvoted in the normal manner too, though.)

Comment: @DerekElkins One small addendum to what you stated which has occurred to me is that when I've used up my quota of comment upvotes for the day, casting a vote to close a post as a duplicate then doesn't cause an automatic upvote of that comment.

Comment: You can see your flagging activity at https://math.stackexchange.com/users/156150/zeraoulia-rafik?tab=topactivity by clicking "helpful flags" in the top left (you can't see other users' activity, just your own).  So you'll be able to see that your flag was indeed helpful.  Be aware though: sometimes clicking that link does take some thick skin when you see that others in the community disagreed with your flagging.  As long as those disagreements are sparse, you're doing fine and should ignore the occasional disagreement.

Comment: Why does it even matter that you flagged this, people agreed, and then the question was closed by others? Clearly you could not VTC yourself or I expect you would have done so. The only behaviour needing apology is your own, for instead of simply asking why something happened, you complain that others must have done some wrong to you, badly enough to leave the site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am sorry for the frustration, but it is of nobody's doing, specifically.

The automatic comment posted upon a vote to close as a duplicate or also a flag as duplicate, the current case, gets automatically deleted by the software once the vote takes effect, because it is considered as redundant. As a general principle comments that are no longer essential get removed.

The people listed in banner are those that voted to close as a duplicate, while you had flagged as a duplicate. Soon, once you reached 3000 points, you will be able to cast a vote as a duplicate, too. In this case the comment will still be deleted, yet you then will be listed in the banner.

Indeed, unfortunately, the information that you had flagged as duplicate is now not very visible anymore. It might be that this side-effect was overlooked, due to the fact that flagging for duplicate is a latter addition, and it is less of an issue for voters (but I am not completely sure about this).

In any case, your flag was useful and appreciated.

Comment: Am sorry for that i don't know about "banner list law " , Thank you so much

Comment: I am glad that I could have been of help. Thanks again for the flag.